# Strange Apache Webdav situation (OSX Will connect, Ubuntu will not)

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, webdav

So basically my situation is that I have an Apache 2.2 webserver running on Linux on another box, and I have it configured to serve up webdav.

Now here's the weird part, I can access the server just fine on my Mac using the "Connect to Server" dialog (even moved like 5GB of files over the connection).  On my Ubuntu desktop cadaver will connect as well and allow me to browse.  However when I try to use Xmarks (BYOS Edition) or the GNOME "Connect to Server" dialog, it gives me a 403 Forbidden error.

My server does digest authentication if that makes any difference.  Here's part of my apache2.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

         DocumentRoot "/path"

<Directory "/path">
       Dav on

       AuthType Digest
       AuthName iTools
       AuthDigestDomain "/"
       AuthUserFile /path/to/WebDavUsers

       Options None
       AllowOverride None

       <LimitExcept GET HEAD OPTIONS>
                    require valid-user
    </LimitExcept>

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from All
</Directory>

<Directory "/path/*/Public">
       Options +Indexes
</Directory>

<Directory "/path/user">
       <LimitExcept GET HEAD OPTIONS>
                    require user user
       </LimitExcept>
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Answer (score 1):

What does apache's error_log say?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is gnome's DAV support is really spotty.

After having this same issue I retested after a debian upgrade and it works again.

OS X seems to be the gold standard. Nothing else actually works in the real world.

Answer (score 1):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) could be useful for tracking the requests and responses in each location - it has helped me with a few webdav issues in the past (such as Windows only recognising '%26' and Apache outputting '&amp;' (or maybe the other way around) for ampersands in dav locations).

Answer (score 1):

WebDAV can be a little spotty with redirects and some clients -- the java DAV library has similar issues. Make sure that your Apache virtual host block has stanzas like this in it (or in the parent)

```
BrowserMatch "Microsoft Data Access Internet Publishing Provider" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "MS FrontPage" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^WebDrive" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^WebDAVFS/1.[0123]" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^gnome-vfs/1.0" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^XML Spy" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^Dreamweaver-WebDAV-SCM1" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "Jakarta Commons" redirect-carefully
```

The definition of this is:

> **redirect-carefully** This forces the
>   server to be more careful when sending
>   a redirect to the client. This is
>   typically used when a client has a
>   known problem handling redirects. This
>   was originally implemented as a result
>   of a problem with Microsoft's
>   WebFolders software which has a
>   problem handling redirects on
>   directory resources via DAV methods

You may have to add the user-agent string you see from XMarks & GNOME if they don't match any of the above and also add them to the list. Everything above except the "Jakarta Commons" is what's configured by default in Red Hat Enterprise for WebDAV.